# Playframework reload not working Mac OSX

Tags: macos, playframework, reload

Since I installed the last Mac OS update (Mac OS X 10.8.3), auto reloading stopped working in Play 2.1.0. When I change a file and save it, the file is compiled (when running with ~run) but when I hit reload on my web browser (already tried with Chrome and Safari) Play Framework don't reload the page. I already tried clean, clean all, reboot my Mac, but nothing resolved the problem.

Do you have any solution for this?

Thank you,

Filipe

Comment: It's not playframework, its JNotify. You can test this by downloading jnotify and running it directl.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, and there is a solution for that? that we can apply to Playframework directly?

Comment: As stated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709325/play-framework-2-1-java-auto-reload-not-working, if you develop with Eclipse, turning off "Build automatically" worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem with play 2.1.0 and I think it has to do with Jnotify